# How to make a combo to reload its store the next time a user interacts with it in ExtJS6?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have a simple combobox backed by an ajax store. I am modifying this store's `proxy.extraParams` based on other fields in the form.

The problems is previous combo options are not resetting when a user presses the down arrow button after I modify the store, as if combo doesn't know that its store has been changed. Is there a way to make the combo reload its store the next time a user interacts with it?

Currently I manually execute `combo.getStore().load()` each time I modify the store params but it results it unnecessary ajax calls. Maybe a user is not even going to interact with that combobox anymore, I want to reload the store only when a user interacts with the combo field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could have a look into the [ExtJS combo code](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/source/ComboBox.html#Ext-form-field-ComboBox-method-doQuery):

```
// If they're using the same value as last time (and not being asked to query all), 
// and the filters don't need to be refreshed, just show the dropdown
if (me.queryCaching && !refreshFilters && queryPlan.query === me.lastQuery) {
    // The filter changing was done with events suppressed, so
    // refresh the picker DOM while hidden and it will layout on show.
    me.getPicker().refresh();
    me.expand();
}

// Otherwise filter or load the store
else {
    me.lastQuery = queryPlan.query;

    if (me.queryMode === 'local') {
        me.doLocalQuery(queryPlan);

    } else {
        me.doRemoteQuery(queryPlan);
    }
}
```

Since [`queryCaching:false`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-queryCaching) would result in unnecessary calls if nothing has been changed, I guess your best bet is `combo.lastQuery = null;`.

Answer (score 2):

You could reload the store everytime the user expands the combobox:

```
listeners: {
        expand: function() {
            this.getStore().load();
        }
    }
```